# how to use column from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im trying to figure out how to use a column from another model in my Profile model

```
User model
  has_one :profile

Profile model
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
```

Tried all possible options to no avail

In my profile model:

```
def get_column_value_from_user_model
    user.username
end
```

What would be the right way to get a value from user model inside my profile model?

When creating a new User that calls above function to get the value from User model, from the Rails Console I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

the username column in User model exists.

Comment: Your get_column_value_from_user_model looks fine. Only problem(rather typo) is in profile model you have written belongs_to :profile that should be belongs_to :user. I don't know it might be a typo

Comment: If it is typo can you paste actual code, that would make it easy to drill down to problem. Because most of your example has typing mistakes(that what I think) ;)

Comment: Ive edited the above snippets indeed a typo my bad, now exact code as I use, I'm using friendly_id and cannot get the value from the user model whatever I tried. So after reading the rails getting started docs on getting values from models I need to be sure the syntax is correct in that case it could be a friendly_id issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

means there is no user object associated with that profile. Could you check what <#your_profile_object>.user_id returns?

Comment: It -works now- I did not do any changes. Since I was using the rails console I did not create a profile object with an Id so therefor it did not work. Thanks for the

Comment: Saving all records from Rails Console made it update correctly with the correct value